# Looking for CLI tool to format data into an image

Tags: database, image, reporting-services

im not sure if this is the right place to ask, but im looking for something that can, via CLI (for automation) input text into an image pattern. Lets say i have an image of a fixed size, and i want to define an area where text A is input, and another area where text B is input, and so on.

Then, i want to be able to link a Database to this tool, so that, when executed, it takes values out of specific colums and outputs an image with the text. I know of tools that can do stuff like this, for example SAP Crystal Reports, but im sure there are tools around that allow a much simpler and lightweight usage.

To clarify, i look for something simple like this website: https://onlinejpgtools.com/add-text-to-jpg just as a CLI tool.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with a little more complicated solution by using the Python Library "Pillow", which should at least give me an interface to input text to and output an image